# Clone windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to clone windows server 2008 R2 to test synch of a quickbooks. I want to test the upgrade with the clone first to reduce risk. What is the best way to clone server for this requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best way" in general. Your tolerance for downtime, the spare hardware you have available, the size of the data involved, and your skill level are all factors.

Presumably you're talking about a physical machine but, if you're not, simply duplicating the VM to another hypervisor might be a good option.

Other options:

- Restore the server from backup to a spare machine. (You do have a working, tested bare-metal backup-- right?)
- Use physical-to-virtual migration software to copy the host to a virtual machine.
- Make a sector-level or filesystem-level clone of the filesystem to a locally-attached disk and boot that in another machine (if the operating system is amenable to such cloning).

There's no single right answer.